# c++: How to take user input as a function argument?

Tags: c++, string, input

I don't know what's wrong with this code... =/

It's a simple code, but...

Doesn't output the result.

Doesn't seem to be taking user input as the argument.

Seems to be some problem with string.

Gives long error comments which I do not comprehend, really long.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int marks;
string result;

string gpa(marks){

if (marks >= 0 && marks <= 49){
    result = "GPA: 0.00\n\n";
}

else if (marks >= 50 && marks <= 54){
    result = "GPA: 1.00\n\n" ;
}

else if (marks >= 55 && marks <= 59){
    result = "GPA: 2.00\n\n" ;
}

else if (marks >= 60 && marks <= 64){
 result = "GPA: 2.30\n\n" ;
}

else if (marks >= 65 && marks <= 69){
    result = "GPA: 2.70\n\n" ;
}

else if (marks >= 70 && marks <= 74){
    result = "GPA: 3.00\n\n" ;
}

else if (marks >= 75 && marks <= 79){
    result = "GPA: 3.30\n\n" ;
}

else if (marks >= 80 && marks <= 84){
    result = "GPA: 3.70\n\n" ;
}

else if (marks >= 85 && marks <= 100){
    result = "GPA: 4.00\n\n" ;
}

else if (marks > 100 && marks < 0){
    result = "Error, please input again.\n\n" ;
}

return result;
}

int main(){

cin >> marks;
gpa (marks);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, you need to give the function signature to `string gpa(int marks)`. Secondly, function `gpa` has a `std::string` return. You are calling it a `void` function.

Comment: So, I changed it from a string to a void function, but thrs still a little error:
variable or field 'gpa' declared void
void gpa(marks){

Comment: Does it also mean that, for any return_type other than int, I should put void?

Comment: You seem to be flailing around, reaching out to less and less likely solutions. I recommend you stop and refresh your memory of your text's section on writing functions before proceeding. Start with basics, a function that takes marks as a parameter and prints it to the screen.

Comment: Yeah sure, in fact I've only just finished the course from SoloLearn, so... kinda starting fresh. I'll be sure to refresh my memories, thank you!

Comment: For reference, if there are "long error messages which you do not comprehend", the compiler's still trying to tell you something and someone else might comprehend them. Put them in the question, at least _try_ to read them, and eventually they'll make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`marks` and `result` can be in block scope, and parameters are denoted using the same syntax as variable declaration, i.e. remove

```
int marks;
string result;
```

Change `string gpa(marks){` to `string gpa(int marks){ string result;` and your main procedure to

```
int main(){

    int marks;
    cin >> marks;
    cout << gpa (marks); //cout is totally optional, it will just print the result from gpa

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `marks` is declared at file scope, so declaring it as an input argument to `gpa` is redundant.

EDIT: You can print the result using `cout << gpa() << endl`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string result;
void gpa();


int main()
{
    gpa();

    return 0;
}
void gpa()
{
    int marks;
    cout<< "please input marks"<<endl;
    cin>>marks;
    system("cls"); //clears terminal in windows OS


    if (marks >= 0 && marks <= 49)
        {
            result = "GPA: 0.00\n\n";
        }

    else if (marks >= 50 && marks <= 54)
        {
            result = "GPA: 1.00\n\n" ;
        }

    else if (marks >= 55 && marks <= 59)
        {
            result = "GPA: 2.00\n\n" ;
        }

    else if (marks >= 60 && marks <= 64)
        {
            result = "GPA: 2.30\n\n" ;
        }

    else if (marks >= 65 && marks <= 69)
        {
            result = "GPA: 2.70\n\n" ;
        }

    else if (marks >= 70 && marks <= 74)
        {
            result = "GPA: 3.00\n\n" ;
        }

    else if (marks >= 75 && marks <= 79)
        {
            result = "GPA: 3.30\n\n" ;
        }

    else if (marks >= 80 && marks <= 84)
        {
            result = "GPA: 3.70\n\n" ;
        }

    else if (marks >= 85 && marks <= 100)
        {
            result = "GPA: 4.00\n\n" ;
        }

    else if (marks > 100 && marks < 0)
        {
            result = "Error, please input again.\n\n" ;
        }


    cout << result <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
int marks;
string result;
string gpa(int marks){definition of function}//modify content string to int if you passing int.
int main(){
cin >> marks;
cout<<gpa (marks);//return result is print
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some explanation!